# Delete all records having value 5x lower than the second highest value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (prices) with two fields, code (char) and price (decimal). I need to find all records with same code, having price 5x lower or less then two highest prices.

E.G. In this case I wish to delete id=1:

```
id   code   price
1    1001   10
2    1001   101
3    1001   40
4    1001   201
5    1002   122
6    1002   50
```

Comment: @lad2025, op said that price must be 5x lower than 2 other prices. 40 * 5 is NOT < 200 and 40 * 5 is NOT < 101

Comment: @Serge 2 highest values or `AVG` of two values?

Comment: Changed 200 to 201.  highest values or AVG of two values? -highest values. If we have 10,20,200 we do not need to delete 10.

Comment: @СергейСоколов Great puzzle :) You could rewrite it as `5 times lower than second highest price` it will be much easier to understand

Comment: "Field" usually refers to a column when talking about relational databases. Do you mean delete *rows*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```sql
DELETE
FROM myTable
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT t2.id
        FROM myTable t2
        WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM myTable t3
            WHERE t3.code = t2.code
            AND t3.price > t2.price * 5
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
            )
    ) t
)
;
```

Comment: Please remove space between `COUNT (*)` to avoid syntax error and change this query to `DELETE` so it match asker requirements :)

Comment: `DELETE t1
FROM myTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM myTable t2
    WHERE t2.code = t1.code
    AND t2.price > t1.price * 5
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)`
It won't work: **`You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause`**

Comment: May be should use join to delete?

Comment: @Serge Please test your solutions, same as above

Comment: @Serge [rextester.demo](http://rextester.com/CJO96006) `You can't specify target table 't1' for update in FROM clause
`

Comment: @lad2025, this error depends on MySQL version. I re-wrote the query to force generating of temp table to avoid this issue.

Comment: @Serge  Your 4th revision looks ok :) Thanks for cooperation

Comment: @lad2025, thanks :). I often find that MySQL is more quirky than Ms SQL and Oracle.

Comment: Thanks for all! Everything works fine. E.G. http://ean13.info/4820163120218.htm  (Prices in the bottom of the page. All wrong prices deleted)

Comment: @СергейСоколов, please accept answer if proposed solution works.

Answer (score 1):

My approach:

```
DELETE t
FROM t
JOIN (SELECT code, 
         REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
         GROUP_CONCAT(price ORDER BY price DESC SEPARATOR ';'), ';', 2)), ';',1))
         AS second_price
     FROM t
     GROUP BY code) s
  ON t.code = s.code
 AND t.price * 5 < s.second_price;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/BAKY3145)**

It is based on selecting second price:

```
SELECT code, 
  REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  GROUP_CONCAT(price ORDER BY price DESC SEPARATOR ';'), ';', 2)), ';',1))  
  AS second_price
FROM t
GROUP BY code;
```

**[Rextester Demo2](http://rextester.com/TLGM87325)**

---

**EDIT:**

Actually it could be much easier:

```
DELETE t
FROM t
JOIN (SELECT code, 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                 GROUP_CONCAT(price ORDER BY price DESC SEPARATOR ';'),
                  ';', 2), ';',-1)  AS second_price
     FROM t
     GROUP BY code) s
  ON t.code = s.code
 AND t.price * 5 < s.second_price;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/GPLXM14373)**

> **Good and fast solution, but honestly, I can not clearly understand it.**

It is very easy to follow:

```
SELECT code, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(price ORDER BY price DESC SEPARATOR ';'),
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(price ORDER BY price DESC SEPARATOR ';'), ';', 2),
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                 GROUP_CONCAT(price ORDER BY price DESC SEPARATOR ';'),
                  ';', 2), ';',-1)
FROM t
GROUP BY code;
```

[image]

Comment: Good and fast solution, but honestly, I can not clearly understand it.

Comment: @СергейСоколов Please check my edit.It is very easy to follow my code :)