# 1093 Error in MySQL table is specified twice

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update some rows.  I only want to update the rows that have ID=0.

The error message I'm receiving is:

## 1093 - Table 'ch_15_posts' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data

This is the code I'm using.  Any suggestions would be welcome!

```
UPDATE ch_15_posts SET ID = (select MAX(ID)+1 as max FROM `ch_15_posts`)
WHERE ID = 0
```

Comment: Use `AUTO_INCREMENT` column

Comment: If you're dividing your data up using N tables instead of a column with N possible values you're probably making a mess of things and violating the principles of proper relational design. A table name like `ch_15_posts` implies there's also some for 1 through 14, which is bad.

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` requires being set on a key, but it needs not be a unique or primary key. Any key will do. This will guarantee unique IDs when inserting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL doesn't allow you to SELECT from a table in the same statement where you UPDATE or DELETE that same table.

```
mysql> UPDATE ch_15_posts SET ID = (select MAX(ID)+1 as max FROM `ch_15_posts`) where id = 0;
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'ch_15_posts' for update in FROM clause
```

There's a [workaround](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/06/23/how-to-select-from-an-update-target-in-mysql/) to do a sort of *double subquery* which evaluates the inner subquery earlier, and storing the result in a temporary table. However, this won't get you what you want, because it only runs the sub-sub-query once, and it will generate a single value and assign it to all your rows where id = 0.

```
mysql> UPDATE ch_15_posts SET ID = (select max from (select MAX(ID)+1 as max FROM `ch_15_posts`) t) where id = 0;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0
```

It looks like you're trying to assign auto-incrementing values to rows where you inadvertently set the value 0. You can't use the MAX(id)+1 method without locking the table, because other concurrent sessions might be inserting new rows while you're doing it. So it's a race condition.

But you can backfill auto-increment values atomically by making the column an auto-increment key.

Demo:

```
mysql> create table c_15_posts (id int );

mysql> insert into c_15_posts values (0), (2), (0), (6), (0), (42);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> alter table c_15_posts modify id int auto_increment primary key;
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from c_15_posts;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  6 |
|  7 |
| 42 |
+----+
```

The rows with 0 don't start at 43, but they do receive unique values. The next insert will get id 43.

Comment: `MySQL doesn't allow you to SELECT from a table in the same statement where you UPDATE or DELETE that same table.` This is untrue (too general). [Counterexample with DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47107721/5070879)

Comment: @lad2025, see my edits. The workaround of using two levels of subqueries is needed to get around the restriction, and it won't achieve the desired result in this case anyway.

Comment: Yes, I know that it won't solve OP's problem because every row will get the same value. The whole point of my comment was that the first statement indicated that something is possible/impossible.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need something like this:

```
UPDATE ch_15_posts AS t1
JOIN (select MAX(ID)+1 as max FROM `ch_15_posts`) AS t2
SET t1.ID = t2.max
WHERE ID = 0
```

Comment: This is still pretty flimsy and subject to race conditions.

Comment: What if there `ID = 0` returns more than one row? Then all will become MAX(X) + 1 instead of consecutive values

Comment: So it will assign the same value to all of them.