# How can I delete multiple MySql Apache table rows in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp, mariadb

I'm using the latest version of XAMPP 2018 with MariaDB and Apache.

I'm executing this sql:

```
 DELETE FROM customer_info 
 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM `customer_info` GROUP BY `paypal_id`) ;
```

and getting this error

```
 Error
 SQL query: 

 DELETE FROM customer_info WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM `customer_info` GROUP BY `paypal_id`)
 MySQL said: Documentation

 #1093 - Table 'customer_info' is specified twice, both as a target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data
```

I have tried different ways to get rid of duplicate paypal_id entries including using COUNT(*) > 1 which also returns an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1093 Error in MySQL table is specified twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165521/1093-error-in-mysql-table-is-specified-twice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MySQL` doesn't allow you to `DELETE` and `SELECT` in the same table.

you can try to use a subquery in `NOT IN`.

```
DELETE FROM customer_info 
 WHERE id NOT IN (
   SELECT ID FROM (
     SELECT MIN(id) Id
     FROM `customer_info` 
     GROUP BY `paypal_id`
   ) t1
 )
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/siDXVeXqLc6Sr91Tw9H1oK/0)

Comment: The ID column is unique and has no repeats as it is on Auto_Increment

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all but the first row, or any small subset of the rows, heres a faster way:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
INSERT INTO new
    SELECT * FROM real WHERE ...;   -- see below
RENAME TABLE real TO old,
             new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```

In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM real ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```