# Mysql 1093 - Table is specified twice

Tags: mysql

I have really searched and this question has been answered  here

[1093 Error in MySQL table is specified twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165521/1093-error-in-mysql-table-is-specified-twice)

but the answer doesn't help me

I have this accounts table

[image: Accounts table]

*But I am facing error  1093 - Table   is specified twice, when trying to update account balance* 
*Although I give the table two names t1 and t2*

```
UPDATE accounts t1 
SET Account_Balance = Account_Balance+(
    SELECT SUM(Credit)-SUM(Debit) 
    FROM accounts  t2   
    WHERE Account_Id=1
)
```

**Create accounts table statement**

```
CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
 `Account_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Account_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
 `Account_Name_English` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `Account_Balance` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 `Credit` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 `Debit` decimal(15,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
 PRIMARY KEY (`Account_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Please make this a complete question by adding some sample table data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an alias doesn't solve the problem of not being able to specify a table that is being updated in a `SELECT` on the right hand side of an expression. One way to work around this issue is to use a multi-table `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE accounts t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(Credit)-SUM(Debit) AS `change`
            FROM accounts
            WHERE Account_Id=1) t2
SET t1.Account_Balance = t1.Account_Balance + t2.change
```

Note I'm not sure the location of the `WHERE Account_Id = 1` is correct; this will update *all* `Account_Balance` fields in `accounts` to their old balance plus the change from `Account_Id` 1. If that is what you want, this is fine, otherwise you might need an additional `WHERE` clause on the `UPDATE` i.e.

```
UPDATE accounts t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(Credit)-SUM(Debit) AS `change`
            FROM accounts
            WHERE Account_Id=1) t2
SET t1.Account_Balance = t1.Account_Balance + t2.change
WHERE Account_Id = 1
```

Or to update all accounts with their own change:

```
UPDATE accounts t1
JOIN (SELECT Account_Id, SUM(Credit)-SUM(Debit) AS `change`
      FROM accounts
      GROUP BY Account_Id) t2 ON t2.Account_Id = t1.Account_Id
SET t1.Account_Balance = t1.Account_Balance + t2.change
```

Here's a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=09603b04a7db2555d91d6134869f1d7d) of all three queries in operation.

Comment: @PHPFan please see this demo, it shows all queries making the changes as described in the answer: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=09603b04a7db2555d91d6134869f1d7d